# What's error 3 in the FreeDos Installer?

Tags: freedos

I'm trying to install FreeDos 1.1 (but 1.0 does the same thing) on a computer of mine, but when it gets to the point where it's installing the FreeDos Command Shell it always gives me a message that says "Warning: Error 3 Occurred. Press any key to continue." When I press a key it gives me a terminal prompt. And if I reboot, FreeDos won't boot. It will just reboot again and again. So what is error 3? And how can I fix it?

PS. I find it interesting that it first calls it a warning and then an error. Usually on a compiler or assembler a warning and an error are two different things, the former meaning that the compilation or assembly went through anyway and it's just warning you about something, the latter meaning that it didn't. Though this is an installer, not a compiler or assembler, it's still a strange thing.